# Emacs line number

Tags: emacs, search-engines

I am having problems obtaining a line number while within an emacs buffer. I have the following number in my initilization file: (setq line-number-display-limit 2000000), and I have verified that line number mode it turned on. When I first enter the (~500) line buffer, emacs provides me with a line number; however, it very quickly switched the line number reading to L??.

Any thoughts as to what could be wrong?

P.S. I have found searching for an answer to this problem nearly impossible as the key character string (L??) is seen by search engines as L(any character)(any character) -- does anybody know a way around this?

Any help will be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any errors/messages in `*Messages*`?

Comment: Do you mean this part: http://i.imgur.com/Augko.png  Can you give us a picture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have very long (wide) lines?   Have you seen **line-number-display-limit-width** ?

> **line-number-display-limit-width** is a variable defined in `C source code'.
>   Its value is 200
>
> Documentation:
>   *Maximum line width (in characters) for line number display.
>   If the average length of the lines near point is bigger than this, then the
>   line number may be omitted from the mode line.

Comment: Yes, that is in fact the problem.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I never knew that, I've just lived with it. For years.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and setting **line-number-display-limit-width** solved it.  I set it using 'customize' and 'Save for future sessions'.  I thought that 'Save for future sessions' would include the 'Set for Current Session'.  But that seems not to be the case.  I had to quit and re-start emacs in order to make it take effect.  That was in a GNU Emacs 22.3.1